# String is incompatible with number (Flow typing optional property with default)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, flowtype, destructuring

Given the following pseudo React Component:

```
type Props = {
  width?: number | string
};

const Component = ({
  width = '100%'
}: Props) => ( /* component body */ )
```

Flow throws the following errors:

```
6:   width = '100%'
     ^ string [1] is incompatible with number [2].
   References:
   2:   width?: number | string
                         ^ [1]
   2:   width?: number | string
                ^ [2]

6:   width = '100%'
             ^ string [1] is incompatible with number [2].
   References:
   6:   width = '100%'
                ^ [1]
   2:   width?: number | string
                ^ [2]
```

The component should accept 3 possible types for `width`: `void | number | string`. Is there a correct way to type this? I can fix the error by removing the default value of `'100%'`, but that solution is less idiomatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [known bug in Flow](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6852), which causes an erroneous type error to be reported when a function has a default argument for a parameter typed as a union.

You can work around it like this:

```
const Component = ({ width }: Props) => ( /* component body */ )

Component.defaultProps = {
    width: '100%',
}
```